# Wordpress Center Mobile Nav

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

Working on this site: http://tinyurl.com/nutvfvb

Just want to know how to get the mobile nav centered. I had to move the menu on desktop over a few pixels, but it looks funny on my iPhone and iPad. Any thoughts on how to adjust that via CSS?

Comment: Have you used media width to accommodate different screen sizes

Comment: Looks to me like there is no media width. Just max width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px){
.navigation-wrapper{margin-left:0px;}
}
```

This will make sure at the desktop size it keeps your navigation bar looking the same but once you drop down to a lower screen resolution it will remove that -margin and allow your `margin:0 auto` to kick back in and center the element

Comment: I need it to hold the nav where it is on the desktop version.